# Install dependencies via pip -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I want to install this library: https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field

I have done like this:

```
(venv) michael@michael:~/PycharmProjects/client$ pip install django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]
Requirement already satisfied: django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers] in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Django>=2.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]) (3.2.3)
Collecting phonenumbers>=7.0.2; extra == "phonenumbers"
  Downloading phonenumbers-8.12.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.6 MB 2.8 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Django>=2.2->django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.3.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Django>=2.2->django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]) (3.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Django>=2.2->django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]) (2021.1)
Installing collected packages: phonenumbers
Successfully installed phonenumbers-8.12.23
```

We can see that this library has installed its dependency: phonenumbers library.

But now I want **to write in requirements.txt that I need django-phonenumber-field of a certain release. So that its dependency should be installed as appropriate**.

In other words how to write requirements.txt for future **pip install -r requirements.txt**.

Could you help me here?

=====ADDED LATER=======
pip freeze > requirements.txt doesn't seem to be appropriate as it will contain all the dependencies. It will become overburden with dependencies. I will forget why a particular library is installed. Whether it is a dependency at all. If it is, what library depends on it.

I want to keep requirements.txt as clear as possible.
In this particular example I want just one directive: install django-phonenumber-field==5.1.0 and manage dependencies yourself.

Wrong way (bloated and unclear what to delete if I stop using the library):

```
django-phonenumber-field==5.1.0
phonenumbers==8.12.23
```

What I want:
django-phonenumber-field==5.1.0 [and all dependencies]

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a requirements.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938554/how-to-create-a-requirements-txt)

Comment: No, it does not. I edited my question. It is not appropriate.

Comment: If you only want to add the top-level dependencies, why not add them yourself as you install them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46816668/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brequirements.txt%5D+top-level

Answer (score 1):

As @jonrsharpe said, you can use `pip freeze` which lists all your dependencies, and redirect the output to your `requirements.txt` file to update it.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: No, you will never find out what you installed yourself and what are the dependencies.

Comment: @Kifsif Ah I see, the only solution I can think of is writing it to `requirements.txt` yourself... but that means having to keep track of any dependency change you make.

Comment: Pip resolves dependencies. I just don't know how to do it in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to create a text file, type the shell commands in, save it and the rename it from `.txt` to `.bat`. Now you can double click the file and it installs the requirements. You could probably even execute the .bat