# pip show only packages with no other dependency in the project

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way to get pip to only show the packages I manually installed, not every package installed because of dependencies?

example requirements.txt file based on only manually installed packages:

```
elasticsearch==7.14.0
matplotlib==3.4.3
numpy==1.21.2
pytz==2021.1
```

But `pip freeze` shows the following:

```
certifi==2021.5.30
cycler==0.10.0
elasticsearch==7.14.0
kiwisolver==1.3.1
matplotlib==3.4.3
numpy==1.21.2
Pillow==8.3.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.1
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.26.6
```

I have tons of projects with the entire `pip freeze` saved as requirements.txt with modules that collide when upgrading.

Comment: [`pipdeptree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54763010/7976758) Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+list+top-level

Comment: pipdeptree is the solution, should be a part of pip, thanks @phd